# How to communicate with all android phones in the wifi network(not wifi direct)..send msg files etc

Tags: android, wifi, chat, multicast

How to communicate with all android phones in the wifi network,(not wifi direct)..send msg files etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a network, the most viable way will be setting up a server. The server will be the point of reference to the devices.

Do some research on REST calls and sockets.

Please, also refer to this topic: [How to communicate two android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602252/how-to-communicate-two-android-devices)